# Weka Time Series Forecast, More Attributes

Tags: data-mining, weka, pentaho, data-warehouse, forecasting

According to [this link](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka), it's explained how to create a forecast model based on date field and measures.

It's working in case when I do not put any other attributes. I need to forward more fields, like SKU no, PointOfSales no etc.

In those cases it returns me an error with 'bad sorting' message even it is sorted asc by date field.

Any help? Am I missing something simple?

EDIT:
working table:

```
DateField TIMESTAMP
Sales     FLOAT
```

Non working table:

```
DateField TIMESTAMP
Sales     FLOAT
SKU       VARCHAR
PoS       VARCHAR
```

Non-working ARFF sample

```
@relation 'C:\\Users\\admpentaho\\Desktop\\file1.arff'
@attribute dat_dok date 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'
@attribute sif_rob {0051S12,0312S13,0762S21,160047,160049,160051,160058,2101S11,250000,250001,250002,250003,250006,250007,250008,2562S12,280001,280002,280003,280004,280005,280006,280007,280008,280009,280010,280011,280012,280013,280014,280015,280017,280018,280019,280020,280021,280022,280023,280024,280027,280028,280043,280044,280045,280047,280049,280050,280053,'2810 S12',3081S21,370002,370003,370007,370015,50004,50005,50006,50007,50008,50015,50018,50019,50023,50034,50070,50073,50076,50077,50101,50103,50112,50116,50118,50138,50148,50149,50161,50185,50186,50196,50198,50199,50203,50204,50236,50238,50239,50240,50241,50242,50243,50244,50245,50246,50251,50252,50264,50272,50273,50274,50279,50295,50296,50299,50307,50308,70001,70003,70005,70006,70007,70008,70013,70014,70015,70016,70017,70018,70028,70029,70032,70033,70035,70039,70040,70042,70043,70044,70046,70048,70049,70065,70070,70073,70074,70078,70079,70085,70087,70088,70089,70092,70096,70097,70098,70100,70136,70137,70144,70156,70167,70168,70169,70241,702426,70243,70245,79003,900327,900334,900336,900353,900354,900356,900362,ALP3150,ALP3151,AM12012,AM12013,AM12014,AM12015,AM12016,AM12017,AM12018,AM12019,AM12050,AMAN57788,AMAN58725,BER3044,BER3047,BER3048,BER3054,BER3070,BIS10001,BIS10108,BIS10223,BIS10224,BIS10289,BIS10307,BIS10309,BIS10313,BIS10315,BIS10362,BIS10369,BIS10370,BIS10371,BIS10379,BIS10380,BIS11107,BIS11208,BIS11236,BIS11237,BIS11238,BIS11304,BIS11306,BIS11320,BIS11327,BIS12015,BIS12018,BIS12072,BIS12074,BIS12076,BIS12078,BIS12079,BIS12080,BIS12081,BIS12083,BIS12084,BIS12091,CAS3372,CAS3376,CAS3377,CAS3378,CAS3379,CE001,CE002,CE003,CE004,CE005,CE106348,CE701850,CE701852,DE0FX3176,DE0SI0012,DE0SI1034,DE0SI1041,DE0SW0209,DE0SX0007,DE0SX0011,DE0SX0012,DE0SX0015,DE0SX0034,DE0SX0041,DE0SX1093,DE0UA2112,DE0UD2100,DE0UN2103,DE0UN2104,DEGN20GN1,DEPA10985,DEPPE1976,DERI10850,DERI40853,DERI50854,DERI60855,DESE26919,DESG86916,DESOF4001,DESOL1001,DESOL2002,DMK3130,DMK3131,DMK3132,DMK3133,DMK8008,DON0006,DON0007,DON0008,DON0013,DON0016,E0111461,E0111463,E0111466,E0111505,E0111506,E0112153D,E0112215,E0112353,E0112488,E0112535,E0112536,E100378,E101119,E101280,E101327,E101331,E101599,E101661,E101661D,E101661K,E101685,E102033,E103896,E105309,E106347,E106348,E106353,E106354,E106356,E106357,E106358,E106359,E106360,E108758,E108759,E1100834,E1100912,E1101523,E1103885,E1104176,E1104579,E1105041,E1106190,E1106349,E1106350,E1106361,E1106362,E1106363,E1106831,E1108159,E1108551,E1109364,E1109697,E1109747,E1111521,E1200368,E1202281,E1202799,E1203602,E1208085,E1208086,E1208662,E1211522,E1308084,E1501017,E1501144,E1501145,E1501146,E1501545,E1502172,E1505223,E1505854,E1507020,E1507948,E1507950,E1601055,E1704580,E1705080,E2006333,E700784,E701153,E701154,E701155,E701197,E701197D,E701596,E701787,E701850,E701850D,E701852,E701852D,E701856,E701856D,E701858,E702665,E704253,E706522,E707095,E707454,E707461,E707605,E707617,E707856,E708265,E708266,E708373,E708374,E708375,E708678,E708685,E708988,E708989,E708990,E709361,E709671,E709884,E710598,EPAL,EVB-2000,EVB-2001,EVB-303,EVB-411,EVB-412,EVB-413,EVB-414,EVB-416,EVB-418,EVB-421,EVB-422,EVB-424,EVB-500293,EVB-500294,EVB-500295,EVB-500296,EVB-500297,EVB-500329,EVB-500330,EVB-500331,EVB-500396,EVB-500397,EVB-500399,EVB-500400,EVB-500402,EVB-500403,EVB-500404,EVB-500405,EVB-500717,EVB-500750,EVB-500751,EVB-500752,EVB-500756,EVB-500778,EVB-500781,EVB-501075,EVB-501076,EVB-502130,EVB-502140,EVB-502290,EVB-502291,EVB-502552,EVB-502680,EVB-502681,EVB-502682,EVB-502683,EVB-502897,EVB-502953,EVB-503051,EVB-503251,EVB-503252,EVB-503255,EVB-503283,EVB-503284,EVB-503290,EVB-503291,EVB-503651,EVB-503654,EVB-503781,EVB-K411,EVB-K413,EVB-K421,EVB-K422,EVB-K424,FI31002,FI31011,FLA000021,FLA000027,FLA000028,FLA000030,FLA000031,FLA000033,FLA000066,FLA000067,FLA000075,FLA000083,FLA000084,FLA000087,FLA000089,FLA000091,FLA000111,FLA000112,FLA000133,FLA000138,FLA000241,FLA000242,FLA000243,FLA000279,FLA000330,FLA000331,FLA000386,FLA000487,FLA000589,FLA000715,FLA000839,FLA001164,FLA001165,FLA001223,FLA001225,FLA001226,FLA001363,FLA001474,FLA001475,FLA001888,FLA001949,FLA002289,FLA002291,FLA002292,FLA002431,FLA002763,FLA002764,FLA002792,FLA002921,FLA002922,FLA002923,FLA002934,FLA002940,FLA002944,FLA002946,FLA002948,FLA002952,FLA002956,FLA002958,FLA002961,FLA002965,FLA002967,FLA002969,FLA002983,FLA002985,FLA002987,FLA002989,FLA002991,FLA002993,FLA003001,FLA003009,FLA003024,FLA003026,FLA003028,FLA003031,FLA003035,FLA003039,FLA003045,FLA003050,FLA003052,FLA003089,FLA003181,FLA003182,FLA003183,FLA003184,FLA003186,FLA003214,FLA003215,FLA003216,FLA003273,FLA003283,FLA003320,FLA003330,FLA003331,FLA003333,FLA003334,FLA003527,FLA003601,FLA003728,FLA003729,FLA003730,FLA003731,FLA003916,FLA003917,FLA003919,FLA003927,FLA003934,FLA004105,FLA004129,FLA004130,FLA004196,FLA004244,FLA004299,FLA004300,FLA004478,FLA004479,FLA004497,FLA004535,FLA004536,FLA004537,FLA004538,FLA004539,FLA004540,FLA004542,FLA004543,FLA004544,FLA004545,FLA004550,FLA004551,FLA004552,FLA004553,FLA004599,FLA004608,FLA004614,FLA005674,FLA006086,FLA006087,FLA290001,FRS064,GE17919,GE19948,GE19949,GEP61504,GL110000,GL210000,GL340100,GL360200,GL360201,GOR1120,GOR1213,GOR1301,GOR1308,GOR1311,GOR1315,GOR1316,GOR1339,GOR1340,GOR1341,GOR1604,GOR1817,GOR1852,GOR1854,GOR1902,GOR1905,GOR1906,GOR1907,GOR1912,GOR1913,GOR1927,GOR1929,GOR1930,GOR1932,GOR1933,GOR1934,GOR1942,GOR1944,GOR1945,GOR1947,GOR1948,GOR1952,H1834230,H2013212,H2017280,H2017283,H2017288,H2295500,H2295800,H2298188,H2395100,H2395166,H2395166A,H2395250A,H2395520A,H2395540,H2395566,H2395840,H2395866,H2395866A,H2494131,H2494241,H2494311,H2496131,H2496241,H2496311,H2498131,H2498241,H2498311,H2499231,H2499241,H2499311,H2817541,H2818541,H2819541,H2943251,H2961001,H2961101,H2961201,HLS001,HOC5006,HOC5007,HOC5108,HOC6008,HOC6009,HOC9000,HOC9001,HOC9002,HOC9007,HOC9009,HOC9015,HUG016,HUG017,HUG019,HUG020,HUG1607,HUGLS0102,HUGLS0103,J1423204,J1764002,J1764003,J1855405,J2061704,J2079703,J2080503,J2103103,J2103303,J2103603,J2129506,J2133406,J2141110,J2142209,J2144402,J2148404,J2265102,J2279902,J2318705,J2364102,J2364202,J2364702,J2364802,J2364902,J2372202,J2375802,J2423819,J2466503,J2500800,J2584509,J2584706,J2589804,J3098916,J3098917,J3101902,J3106903,J3166005,J3184001,J3185101,J3185401,J3276504,J3276805,J3277102,J3309702,J3328304,J3333602,J3362404,J3365006,J3369805,J3382502,J3398204,J3519004,J3646716,J3660202,J3666000,J3666400,J3682507,J3699704,J3803900,J3809405,J3834607,J3835107,J3841200,J3854102,J3854402,J3854702,J3855002,J3887401,J3897402,J3898002,J3922901,J3954502,J3983101,J3995301,J4010601,J4023602,J4023702,J4069403,J4100102,J4145904,J4146303,J4272302,J4290002,J4292000,J4292701,J4293401,J4307300,J4313100,J4318700,J431900,J4319000,J4346101,J43709,J4394702,J4432601,J4458601,J4459701,J4501700,J4670402,J4730908,J4736310,J4748307,J4775203A,J4775304A,J4789400,J4789502,J4952004,J4985800,J4993200,J4993300,J5217309,J5217907,J5218006,J5218106,J5218405,J5337500,J5462500,J5479200,J5705100,J5705200,J5705300,J5768200,J5768300,J5787900,J5800300,J5805000,J5806105,J5852100,J5883001,J6008100,J6008400,J6037300,J6041600,J6046200,J6047400,J6057301,J6057401,J6127800,J6148800,J6212700,J6213300,J6213800,J6213900,J6214000,J6214100,J6214200,J6214300,J6214400,J6214500,J6214600,J6214700,J6214800,J6214900,J6215300,J6215400,J6215600,J6215800,J6216000,J6216100,J6216200,J6216300,J6216400,J6216600,J6216700,J6217000,J6246000,J6250800,J6281000,J6287000,J6306700,J6307300,J6308600,J6309100,J6354503,J6390201,J6394600,J6424300,J6424400,J6428503,J6428901,J6454700,J6460700,J6463100,J6468500,J6479400,J6479600,J6489501,J6504800,J6504900,J6638000,J6651100,J6667301,J6673203,J6686800,J6705700,J6764800,J6766002,J6766100,J6777800,J6849200,J6849300,J6849400,J6849600,J6849900,J6889701,J702226,J702227,J702228,J702229,J7023900,J7125300,J7125700,J7144900,J7188400,J7290900,J7324500,J7519300,J7567700,J7567800,J7650100,J7650400,J7650400D,J7653400,J7653400D,J7656600,J7693500,J7696700,J7706600D,J7759001,J7759101,J7869100,J8003704,J8046100,J8060201,J8060500,J8083500,J8083600,J8083701,J8083901,J8084001,J8084100,J8084201,J8084300,J8084400,J838704,J838810,JCC003,JJB033,JJB035,JJB036,JJB047,JJB048,JJB049,JJB050,JJB051,JJB052,JJJB0030,JJJB010,JJJB0106,JJJB0114,JJJB0118,JJJB012,JJJB0120,JJJB0121,JJJB0124,JJJB0125,JJJB013,JJJB019,JJJB020,JJJBO20135,JJOB020415,JJRX503204,JO14007,JO14008,JO14009,JO14010,JO14011,JO14016,JO14017,JO14018,JO14019,JO14050,JOB006,JRE003,JRE004,JRE007,JRE008,JRE010,K3086160,K3158150,K3262010,K3270661,K3270670,K3415800,K3417600,K3482121,K3519880,K3527090,K3568140,K3570140,K3571140,K3697800,K3698210,K3745030,K3824120,K3855270,K4521020,K4584040,K4700430,K4725040,K4729010,K4739350,K4762230,K4762240,K4845030,K4845040,K4933950,K4933960,K4934100,K4934110,K4961350,K4961360,K4961450,K4961800,K4961810,K5016385,K5027020,K5110510,K5115120,K5605000,K5606000,KLBT0107,KLBT0108,KLFT0105,MI14045,MI14046,MI14047,MI14048,MP00314,MP00317,MP00331,MP00419,MP00580,MP00834,MP00999,MP01064,MP01084,MP01098,MP01152,MP01154,MP01214,MP01247,MP01254,MP01321,MP01369,MP01435,MP01455,MP01456,MP01543,MP01584,MP01593,MP01595,MP01600,MP01601,MP01605,MP01606,MP01608,MP01640,MP01645,MP01653,MP01689,MP01694,MP01701,MP01865,MP01866,MP02051,MP02059,MP02126,MP02183,MP02408,MP02410,MP02420,MP02459,MP02491,MP02563,MP02610,MP02615,MP02936,MP02952,MP02968,MP02974,MP02977,MP03017,MP03020,MP03263,MP04125,MP04261,MP04321,MP04474,MP04703,MP05206,MP05313,MP05314,MP05460,MP05462,MP05716,MP05768,MP06144,MP06145,MP06198,MP06339,MP06349,MP06436,MP06466,MP06467,MP06468,MP06609,MP06610,MP07183,MP07248,MP07249,MP07290,MP07313,MP07673,MP07696,MP07702,MP07876,MP08113,MP08119,MP08128,MP08136,MP08225,MP08247,MP08248,MP08302,MP08318,MP08416,MP08474,MP08476,MP08962,MP09019,MP09336,MP09540,MP09558,MP10118,MP11079,MP11085,MP11259,MP11543,MP11560,MP11664,MS008,PCF001,PCF003,PCF004,PCF005,PCOR001,PEB001,PEB002,PEB003,PEB004,PEB005,PEB006,PEB013,PEB014,PEB018,PEB019,PEB020,PFR004,PFR007,PFR008,PFRS004,PFRS005,PFRS007,PHUG003,PHUG004,PHUG005,PJ&J103,PJ&J105,PJ&J106,PJ&J107,PJ&J108,PJ&J110,PJ&J113,PJ&J114,PJ3185401,PJ4010601,PJ7519300,PJB001,PJB006,PJB007,PJB009,PJB010,PJB011,PJB012,PJB013,PJB014,PJB015,PJB019,PLM001,PLM002,PNT001,PO0045,PO0046,POB001,POB002,POB003,POB0033,POB004,POB005,POB006,POB010,POB011,POB012,PPJ5800300,RE13207,RE13208,RE13209,RE13210,RE13211,RE13212,RE13304,RE13307,RE13308,RE13309,RE13310,RE13311,RH2395540,RJ5217907,RJ5218006,RJ5218106,RJ5218405,RJ5986705,RJ6213300,RJ6213800,RJ6214000,RJ6214600,RJ6215800,RJ7759101,RS0107,RSKO004,RSKO005,RSKO006,RSKO007,RSKO008,RSKO009,RSKO010,RSKO011,RSKO012,RSKO013,RSKO014,RSKO015,RSKO016,RSKO017,SAN1220,SAN2000,SAN2003,SAN2029,SAN2201,SAN2302,SAN2400,SAN2401,SAN2502,SAN3256,SAN5029,SKO0001,SKO1013,SKO1064,SKO1381,SKO1382,SKO1411,SKO161,SKO163,SKO164,SKO169,SKO171,SKO1718,SKO1720,SKO2093,SKO2094,SKO3320,SKO3564,SKO3603,SKO3683,SKO3729,SKO3730,SKO3812,SKO4194,SKO4272,SKO4281,SKO611,SKO612,SKO706,SKO711,SKO724,SKO777,SKO944,SKO988,SP13200,SP13202,SP13203,SP13204,SP13205,SP13206,SP13300,SP13301,SP13302,SP13303,SP13306,TEFS11E27,UNI12215721,UNI14402415,UNI14520114,UNI14520312,UNI15440220,UNI15440321,UNI15440422,UNI15667103,UNI16661001,UNI16874401,UNI16874601,UNI17112413,UNI17137701,UNI17137901,UNI17139805,UNI17276602,UNI17783401,UNI18304712,UNI19047102,UNI19102908,UNI19249808,UNI19418414,UNI19421510,UNI19423004,UNI19461610,UNI19656103,UNI19905101,UNI26704201,UNI39047202,V0001,V0002,V1050001,V1050002,V1051001,V1051002,V1051011,V1052001,V1052002,V1052003,V1052007,V1052008,V1052009,V1052010,V1052011,V1052045,V1052046,V1052047,V1052048,V1053001,V1053002,V1053004,V1054001,V1054002,V1054004,V1055001,V1055002,V1100012,V1100013,V1100014,V1155001,V1155002,V1250001,V1250002,V1250003,V1250004,V1250005,V1250006,V1251001,V1251002,V1251003,V1251004,V1251023,V1251024,V1251032,V1251038,V1253001,V1253002,V1253003,V1253004,V1253005,V1253006,V1253007,V1253008,V1253019,V1254002,V1254003,V1254004,V1255001,V1255002,V1255003,V1255004,V1545001,V1545002,V1545003,V1545004,V1545005,V1545007,V1758001,V1758002,V1758003,V1758004,V1859001,V1859002,V1859003,V1859004,V1860001,V1860002,V1860003,V1946001,V1946002,V1946003,V1946006,V1947001,V2061001,V2061002,V2061003,V2061004,V2061005,V2061006,V2365002,V2365003,V2700007,V2800001,V2800002,V2800013,V2800014,V3300051,V3887001,V3887002,VA001,VA002,VA003,VA4103101412,VA4103101414,VA4106101412,VA4106101414,VA4703101436,VA4706101436,VA4903121412,VA4903121414,VA4906121412,VA4906121414,VA56703101402,VA56706101402,VA57666101451,VIPC001,WES3021,WES3024,WES3026,WES3031,WES3035,WES3069,WES3079,WES3080,ZOT1000,ZOT1001,ZOT1002,ZOT1003,ZOT1004,ZOT1005,ZOT1006,ZOT1009,ZOT1011,ZOT1013,ZOT1014,ZOT1043,ZOT1044,ZOT1045,ZOT1046,ZOT16003,ZOT16004,ZOT16005,ZOT2000,ZOT2001,ZOT2010,ZOT2025,ZOT2028,ZOT2043,ZOT2045,ZOT2046,ZOT2047,ZOT2047D,ZOT2108,ZOT2110,ZOT2402,ZOT2403,ZOT2405,ZOT2406,ZOT2407,ZOT3003,ZOT3004,ZOT3005,ZOT3014,ZOT3076,ZOT3106,ZOT3107,ZOT3108,ZOT3109,ZOT3135,ZOT3136,ZOT3137,ZOT3152,ZOT3153,ZOT3154,ZOT6006,ZOT6007,ZOT61396,ZOT9043,ZOT9044}
@attribute vred_rab numeric
@data
'2013/01/03 00:00:00.000',PHUG005,4255.3
'2013/01/03 00:00:00.000',PJ7519300,17708.2
'2013/01/03 00:00:00.000',PNT001,13780.7
'2013/01/09 00:00:00.000',GEP61504,1117.8
'2013/01/09 00:00:00.000',TEFS11E27,341.6
'2013/01/10 00:00:00.000',280001,-9000.7
'2013/01/10 00:00:00.000',280005,-2663
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details about the data you are working with and the process done to get to the error?  The sample data sets do not contain these attributes.

Comment: I edited question, is that enough? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a sample ARFF file that could be used for reference instead? Just the header and a few lines should be enough.

Comment: I edited question again :)

Comment: The ARFF is inconsistent with the Non-Working Table Structure.  Also, I see a value of '341.6Save as Draft' that may not be correct.

Comment: No, no it's my coping mistake (Save as Draft).
How inconsistent? It's made by pentaho plugin.